# How do I implement IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to convert a `type` to `IEnumerable` with no luck.

This is the `type` I am trying to make as a `IEnumerable`.

```
public class Container<T>
{        
    public int GetInt { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that gets the data,

```
Container<String> results = client.GetStuff(query);
```

So I trying to convert the variable `results` to `IEnumerable<string>`, but I have no idea how to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction to do this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What is `GetStuff`? Here does it get the `string` data from? And you can't convert a class to `IEnumerable`, you can implement it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, the methode to fill the container class.

Comment: How? What? When?

Comment: @GrantWinney, I think what I am after is to have `Container` to implement the `IEnumerable` interface

Comment: But how? What data is returned?

Comment: And btw, you mean `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I mean `IEnumrable<T>`

Comment: We can give you the code that shows the interface outline, but that isn't very useful. You have to come up with something concrete.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Tomas Lycken has the answer. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to use an instance of a type as an `IEnumerable<T>`, the type must *implement* `IEnumerable<T>`. You indicate that you want to do this by adding `: IEnumerable<T>` after the class name in the declaration:

```
public class Container<T> : IEnumerable<T>
// ...
```

When you do that, you will get compiler errors complaining that you haven't implemented all the required members. Your IDE should be able to auto-generate stubs for them, but this is what you'll have to do:

```
public class Container<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // forward the non-generic version to the generic version
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    // implement GetEnumerator from the generic interface
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, the most common way to implement your own `IEnumerable<T>` is to wrap a built-in one, e.g. a `List<T>` or an array. If that's what you're doing, you can just forward the `GetEnumerator()` call to the inner instance and be done.

If you want to do something more sophisticated, you can e.g. build your iteration protocol using the `yield return` construct:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    // do some work
    // then return the first element:
    yield return default(T); // yeah, you probably have an actual value

    // do some more work
    // return another value:
    yield return default(T);

    // if you want to abort the iteration prematurely
    // e.g. based on some condition
    // you can
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: Or my personal favorite `yield return`.

Comment: Exactly. Implement this Container of yours using a List or Array or some such already-enumerable collection class. Nothing's to be gained from reinventing the flat tire.

Comment: Well that will do it. Thanks, I can't accept for 2 minutes.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Thanks, I included an example to show how `yield` can bring value on top of just iterating over an inner collection.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `results` is of `Container<String>` and as the `Container` generic class is defined you can't cast it to an `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want so you should declares that `Container<T>` implements this interface and provide an implementation.

```
public class Container<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // provide an implementation of the missing members.
}
```